# Android: TabHost and modify value textedit

Tags: java, android, android-tabhost

Good afternoon.

I hope you can help me with a problem I guess is caused by ignorance of Ta`b`Host.

It is possible have a tabhost with 3 tabs, where visual components are exactly the same, with the same ID, and give them value as the selected tab?

For example, in the 3 tabs I have three `EditExt` called

```
R.id.textNivel1Acierto
R.id.textNivel1Objetivo 
R.id.textNivel1Fallo
```

Can you have the same ID in the 3 tabs?
what I want is that those 3 `TextView` show a different value depending on the tab

I put the code with some things I've been trying and I said it did not work as I wanted, as it is currently fails when you click a tab

```
public class Resultados extends Activity {  

   TabHost tabs;
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

         setContentView(R.layout.resultados);


      tabs=(TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
         tabs.setup();  

         TabHost.TabSpec spec=tabs.newTabSpec("tabSumas");
         spec.setContent(R.id.tabSumas);
         spec.setIndicator("",     this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.boton_suma));
         tabs.addTab(spec);  

         spec=tabs.newTabSpec("tabRestas");
         spec.setContent(R.id.tabRestas);
         spec.setIndicator("",     this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.boton_resta));
         tabs.addTab(spec);  

         spec=tabs.newTabSpec("tabAritmetica");
         spec.setContent(R.id.tabAritmetica);
         spec.setIndicator("",     this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.boton_aritmetica));
         tabs.addTab(spec);  

         tabs.setCurrentTab(0);

//           TextView tAciertos = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textNivel1Acierto);
//           TextView tFallos = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textNivel1Fallo);
//           TextView tObjetivo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textNivel1Objetivo);



//           tAciertos.setText("0");
//           tFallos.setText("0");
//           tObjetivo.setText("0");



         tabs.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() { 
                @Override   
                public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {       


                              if (tabId.equals("tabSumas"))
                              {
                                    cambiaValores(0, "0");
//                                      TextView tAciertos=(TextView) tabs.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).findViewById(R.id.textNivel1Acierto);
//                                      TextView tFallos=(TextView) tabs.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).findViewById(R.id.textNivel1Fallo);
//                                      TextView tObjetivo=(TextView) tabs.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).findViewById(R.id.textNivel1Objetivo);

//                                      tAciertos.setText("0");
//                                      tFallos.setText("0");
//                                      tObjetivo.setText("0");

                              }else if (tabId.equals("tabRestas"))
                              {
//                                      TextView tAciertos=(TextView) tabs.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).findViewById(R.id.textNivel1Acierto);
//                                      TextView tFallos=(TextView) tabs.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).findViewById(R.id.textNivel1Fallo);
//                                      TextView tObjetivo=(TextView) tabs.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).findViewById(R.id.textNivel1Objetivo);



//                                      tFallos.setText("1");
//                                      tObjetivo.setText("1");
//                                      tAciertos.setText("1");
                                    cambiaValores(1, "1");


                              }else if (tabId.equals("tabAritmetica"))
                              {
//                                      TextView tAciertos=(TextView) tabs.getTabWidget().getChildAt(2).findViewById(R.id.textNivel1Acierto);
//                                      TextView tFallos=(TextView) tabs.getTabWidget().getChildAt(2).findViewById(R.id.textNivel1Fallo);
//                                      TextView tObjetivo=(TextView) tabs.getTabWidget().getChildAt(2).findViewById(R.id.textNivel1Objetivo);


//                                      tAciertos.setText("2");
//                                      tFallos.setText("2");
//                                      tObjetivo.setText("2");
                                    cambiaValores(2, "2");

                              }

                  }
                });





   }

   public void cambiaValores(int iD, String texto)
   {

         TextView tAciertos=(TextView) tabs.getTabWidget().getChildAt(iD).findViewById(R.id.textNivel1Acierto);
         TextView tFallos=(TextView) tabs.getTabWidget().getChildAt(iD).findViewById(R.id.textNivel1Fallo);
         TextView tObjetivo=(TextView) tabs.getTabWidget().getChildAt(iD).findViewById(R.id.textNivel1Objetivo);

          tAciertos.setText(texto);
          tFallos.setText(texto);
          tObjetivo.setText(texto);
   }
```

}

One more thing is necessary to
"`public class extends TabActivity Results`" or better with "`public class Result extends Activity`"?

I hope you can tell me I'm wrong
Thanks

Comment: If you have three tabs which are identical then why do you use 3 different ids for the tab content?

Comment: because they do not wear well tabhost, believed to be doing well ..thought that each tab should have a different ID.



of course I know I will use 9 textview (3 per tab) would have no problem, but it can be done only with 3?
design in all tabs is the same, just change the information displayed

Comment: dont know if I explain, eg if I want tab1 pulse in place (just an example, I'll read the values ​​of a database)
Well: 1
Mal: 1
Time: 1

If I press the tab2
Good: 2
Bad: 2
Time: 2

pulse if the tab3
Good: 3
Bad: 3
Time: 3

Comment: It's possible. Post the layout file you have for the activity.

Comment: ok, this is the layout, maybe its no the best way to do.. the layout is a "table" of 6 rows and 4 columns

but.. with every id repeat, it show a warning.. for example: Duplicate id @+id/textNivel5Objetivo, already defined earlier in this layout.

  Thanks for your time

put a link of layout, cause its more than 30000 characters

http://tny.cz/df24e9cb